# Journey Building Interaction Event not firing

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

I created an interaction in a journey builder which has an entry event associated with a data extension.

Below documentation says that this event can be fired by using Automation studio or POSTing an event using REST API

https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/events/how-to-fire-an-event.html

Automation Studio options works perfectly but POST is not working. The record got inserted in the data extension correctly but the event is not firing.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is the response when you POST to the Fire Event API?  Does a subscriber record already exist for the record or is the subscriber completely new?

Comment: Subscriber is created successfully in the data extension .. It's a new subscriber altogether

Comment: Check out the answer at: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104394/sending-an-email-from-a-journey-builder-interaction-to-a-subscriber-not-in-all-s  Either a subscriber record will need to already exist prior to firing them into the JB interaction or the DE needs to be configured as root.

Comment: My DE is already set as root and has one-to-one relationship. Email is still not getting sent

Comment: Below is how I am doing the post. The ContactID I have used is random. Its succeeding and creating a row in the DE.
Is that right?

 `   {
    "ContactID":"ID601",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"ContactEvent-692974ec-e256-e51e-e528-  a638fb1b7554",
"Data": {
    "Cust_Id":"123321117766",
    "FirstName": "FFFdd",
    "LastName": "LLLLss",
    "EmailAddress": "maneesh_83@yahoo.co.in",
    "SubscriberKey": "123321117766"
}
} `

Comment: ContactID is how you identify the subscriber, it shouldn't be a random value. Alternatively, you can use ContactKey which is the same as SubscriberKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your request in your comment, that will never work. Note that contactID is a number but you are passing a string in your payload (`ID601`). Also, I would suggest using contactKey instead of contactID. Apparently, Contact ID is for internal use. Update your Attribute Group to create a one-to-one root relationship to the **Contact Key** of the Contact Record (instead of Contact ID) and then change your payload request to:

```
{  
   "contactKey":"ID601",
   "EventDefinitionKey":"ContactEvent-692974ec-e256-e51e-e528-a638fb1b7554",
   "Data":{  
      "Cust_Id":"123321117766",
      "FirstName":"FFFdd",
      "LastName":"LLLLss",
      "EmailAddress":"maneesh_83@yahoo.co.in",
      "SubscriberKey":"123321117766"
   }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Eliot, with your solution above, I have been able to trigger the Event but email is not going. Its failing with the below error -

    Failed - ExactTarget.JourneyBuilder.Activities.EmailActivity.EmailAddress:     Error binding data bound member.

Its a one-to-one relationship and set as root also .. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Maneesh, this would indicate that you have not configured the Channel Address Order for Send Email Activities. The Channel Address Order determines which channel address field takes precedence for all send Activities. Open Contact Builder and select the **Contacts Configuration** menu item. Then, in the **Email** panel click on **Edit**, then **Add Address** and select the Attribute Group containing the email address, then click on **Save**. You can change the precedence of a channel address by dragging the row in the panel. When you're finished, click on **Save**.

Comment: Thanks Eliot! I am very close now I believe. I configured the Channel Address Order and now there is a different error message - 

**Error Code 10 - Subscriber is missing required attribute value for LLYSubscriberKey**  

LLYSubscriberkey is an attribute in All Subscribers. I have it in my data extension also and also in the API call.. it is coming successfully in the DE..  

What do you think is causing this?

Comment: Hello Eliot, any thoughts you could share here ?

Comment: If you open the All Subscribers record for this subscriber, is there an LLYSubscriberkey value for that subscriber? I'm wondering if this error relates to the All Subscribers record (which is different from the Contact Record).

Comment: This record is not even making it to the All Subscribers .. It gets loaded successfully in the data extension but while on its way to All Subscribers, its dropping off because of the required attribute (LLYSubscriberKey) .. this attribute is present in the DE so should get loaded in all subscribers also .. not sure why its not

Comment: Hi, the Contact Record and Subscriber record aren't related. If there is a required attribute in the Subscriber Record, you will need to put it in there manually or using the SOAP API. If the Subscriber Record doesn't exist for a Contact, then one will be created once it reaches the Send Email Activity in the Journey, but it won't magically populate any custom attributes in the Subscriber Record.